# How to update field in array, only if other field matches value in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, updates

I tangle a bit in jungles of query and update selectors of MongoDb.

Situation: We have Companies collection. smth like this

```
Companies.find({}) =>
 {_id: 1, item_amount: 5}, 
 {_id: 2, item_amount: 7}, 
 {_id: 3, item_amount: 10}
```

And we have Users collection with some structure. User want to buy any item and it may decrement value in Companies and increment in Users, with one condition - user may know where he buy the item.

```
{userId: _id,
 ownedItems: 
  [{company_id: 2, item_amount: 3},
  {company_id: 1, item_amount: 5}]
}
```

Ok. How i may Users.update(), if user want to buy, for example, 5 items from `{_id: 3}` (we don't know if user has field for `company_id: 3`)

I thought it may be smth like this:

`Companies.update({_id: 3}, {$inc: {item_amount: - 5}})`
&&

`Users.update({userId: _id}, {$set: {'ownedItems[x].company_id': 3}, $inc{'ownedItems[x].item_amount': 5})`

But of cause there are some problems. 
How i may know the `[x]` for each clint? Sort it? and what if I will need to add new Company? 
Is `$set` will work if field `'ownedItems[x].company_id'` does not exist?

May be I may check smth in IF/Else statement. With, for example, `$exist`, or `$cond`( for aggregation) selectors. But .find() always return a cursor (is it?), not true or false. So what may do? How may I use aggregation selectors? Like this:

`Users.find({_id: userId}, {$cond: [{$eq: ['owenedItem[x].company_id', _someId_]}, {$set:{...}}, {$push: {...}}]})`

Will it work?

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you want to use the $elemMatch operator in conjunction with the '$' positional operator:

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/elemMatch/
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/positional/

Let's take your example.  Let's say you want to find the element in the user's "ownedItems" list where the "company_id" is 3, and update that element's "item_amount" by 5.  That can be done in a single update statement like so:

```
Users.update( { userId: _id, ownedItems : { $elemMatch : { company_id : 3 } } },
              { $inc : { ownedItems.$.item_amount : 5 } } )
```

The **$elemMatch** operator makes it explicit which of the elements of the list you're querying for.  You can then use the **$** operator in the modifier clause to refer to that matched element and make changes to it.

If the "ownedItems" list of the user does not have any entry matching { "company_id" : 3 } then the above update will not do anything.  If that happens, you can do a second update with the **$addToSet** operator to add a new entry like so:

```
Users.update( { userId: _id },
              { $addToSet : { ownedItems : { company_id : 3, item_amount : 5 } } } )
```

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/addToSet/

Comment: thanks for that answer! But may be I miss out some things.. I see here a 2 problems for my example. First, I do not know if Users collection have `company_id` so what happens if there is no field in user doc. And second 'problem', may be I'm not familiar with **$** operator, but as I thought it is return the **first** match of the query's array, so in array, it can increment the value, for example, of company_id = 1, if it will be the first match for query (sorry for so silly questions :) )?

Comment: Good point!  In that case, you'll have to do 2 updates.  You can check the result of the original update I mentioned, and if it doesn't actually change anything (because the query didn't match), then do another update that uses $addToSet to add a new entry to the ownedItems list.  I'll update my answer with the details.  I'm not sure I understand your second question.  Is it a problem that it will increment the first match in the list?  Do you expect multiple entries in the list to have the same company_id?